# IMG that overflows its fixed width container, becoming large as browser window

Tags: css

If I have a code like this:

```
<div id='container'>

  ...some stuff....

  <div id='img_box'>
     <img src=''>
  </div>

</div>
```

in which "CONTAINER" has a fixed width (i.e. 1200px), if I set IMG width to 100%, she span only for 1200px, so costrained in its container.

I would like that image could span across the entire width of browser window (minus some lateral margins), horizonally centered.... so that IMG oveflow its container in fluid way while enlarging window.

Is it possible in such way?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the new css viewport units for this

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/Wte3f/)**

```
img
{
    display:inline-block;
    width: 100vw; /* 100% of viewport width */
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No. The only way that might be possible is to position the `img` tag or `#img_box` absolutely, and make sure that no parent containers are `position:relative`.
The `img` will always be the width of a parent container if it has an explicit width and your image is set to 100% width.